# Como criar um listView Flutter dentro de outro com opção de expandir e fechar?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou precisando criar um listView Flutter dentro de outro com opção de abrir e fechar esse outro. Segue um exemplo de imagem de como queria fazer. Nessa imagem eu abri somente a categoria 2. Quero poder expandir ou fechar como nessa imagem.

Tentei procurar, mas não encontro nada assim. Só acho listView.builder com outro listView, mas não expandem.[Exemplo de como queria que fosse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fXP8.jpg)

O código que fiz ficou assim, mas não é assim que estava pensando!

[Código de como está atualmente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzRcX.png)

Comment: Fala Diogo, bem vindo ao site. Do jeito que está, acho que vai ser difícil obter uma resposta. Poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes? Por exemplo, o que você já tentou fazer, qual o comportamento que obteve, se deu algum erro e em qual linha, ou um exemplo que dê para rodar e compilar localmente, sem precisar ficar imaginando. Assim quem for ler consegue entender sua dúvida melhor. Do jeito que tá parece que você quer que alguém faça uma parte de um trabalho para você, ao invés de tirar uma dúvida. Um abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: Valeu pela dica. Adicionei o meu código de como está atualmente!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acredito que o widget ***ExpansionTile*** possa resolver o seu problema. Referência da documentação [aqui](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html).
Normalmente o widget usado como filho (child) de uma **listview** é o widget **listtile**, mas usando o widget **expansiontile** como filho de uma **listview** poderás adicionar uma lista de widgets como filhos do **expansiontile**.

O **expansiontile** age como um **listtile** colapsável (caso o atributo **children** não esteja vazio) com um dropdown button no final que revela ou esconde a lista de widgets (atributo children).

Este é o código da minha tentativa de reproduzir a UI da imagem na pergunta

```
ListView(
        children: [
          ExpansionTile(
            title: const Text('2 International Lager'),
            children: [
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                title: const Text('2A International Lager'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                title: const Text('2B International Lager'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () {},
                title: const Text('2C International Lager'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('3 Czech Lager'),
            children: [],
          ),
          const ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('4 Pale Malty European Lager'),
            children: [],
          )
        ],
      )
```

O código reproduziu a seguinte UI[image: imagem]